# Low poly curve to a high poly curve ?

Tags: modeling, bevel

i want to make this set of faces more polished , more round , just having more faces forming a more defined curve

normally i do a subdivision with the modifier and crease the faces from top and below but the model is too complex for that [image]

how am i supposed to do ?

temporary file link:
https://we.tl/t-r7BXMT7Vxd

thanks

Comment: If possible please attach the .blend so we can test out what works in this case https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i got an error when uploading to you site , i put a wetransfer link

Comment: It's not too complicated, it just has bad geometry. I would separate the desktop, fix geometry and use subsurf on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topology is not good, therefore it limits the improvements you can make. But you can make that corner much rounder with bevels:

- Go in *Edit* mode > *Edge select* mode.
- Select the edges of your corner.
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> and drag your mouse.
- Press <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>scrollwheel</kbd> to increase or decrease the amount of edges of your bevel.
- Your corner is rounder.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot , i didnt know i could use a bevel for this king of usage